# spark sql Ignore Null Values in partition by clause column

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

Please find the below query. The partition column has Null Values and I want to ignore Null values while doing last_value in partition column too.

```
select * from (
select col1, col2,state_time,
coalesce (CASE WHEN ra.col2 ='' THEN NULL ELSE col2 end,
last_value (col2) IGNORE NULLS OVER
 (partition by col1 order by state_time ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING )
) as job_icims_id_der
 from delta_source_db.recruiting_activity ra
 order by state_time desc) inq where col1 is null
 and col2 is null and job_icims_id_der is  not null order by state_time
  limit 10
```

[image]

Comment: And what is the issue with your query?

Comment: You cannot ignore some values in partitioning because every input row need to be assigned to some partition. What do you expect to be the result of an analytic function for such ignored rows? Anyway you can use or not use the calculated result for any given row depending on other columns (regardless of is this a partition column or not). Or please provide more details of what you try to achieve, preferably with source data and desired output in text format.

Answer (score 0):

In SparkSQL, the ignore flag is a second argument as in:

```
last_value(col2, true) over
    (partition by col1
     order by state_time
     ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
    ) as job_icims_id_der
```

I usually recommend `first_value()` for this logic, though:

```
first_value(col2, true) over
    (partition by col1
     order by state_time desc
    ) as job_icims_id_der
```

It does not require the window frame specification.